# stripe: how to make sure the connected account receives the right amount

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm building a market place (let's say airbnb).

People who receive money (owners) onboard on Stripe using the Account Link method https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom/hosted-onboarding

The payment is done using Stripe Checkout (for the renters).  I handle the application fee using the collect then transfer method:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide?platform=web&payment-ui=checkout#accept-payment

Our typical application fee is 10%, so if I want the owner to get 100, I build a Checkout URL for 110, the breakdown is then: 100 for the owner, 3 or so for Stripe for their fees and the rest 7 or so for us.

I use this code (slightly modified from the previous link):

```
SessionCreateParams params =
  SessionCreateParams.builder()
    .setMode(SessionCreateParams.Mode.PAYMENT)
    .addLineItem(
      SessionCreateParams.LineItem.builder()
                    .setQuantity(1L)
                    .setPriceData(roomPricePlusServiceFeePriceData)
                    .build()
    )
    .setPaymentIntentData(
      SessionCreateParams.PaymentIntentData.builder()
        .setApplicationFeeAmount(applicationFeeTotal)
        .setTransferData(
          SessionCreateParams.PaymentIntentData.TransferData.builder()
            .setDestination("{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}")
            .build()
        )
        .build()
    )
    .setSuccessUrl("https://example.com/success")
    .setCancelUrl("https://example.com/cancel")
    .build();
```

As you see, the 100 for the owner is never set, it's roomPricePlusServiceFeeData - applicationFeeTotal.
All of this is working.

Now I want to modify the code to provide services without any service fee for renters but I still want them to pay for the Stripe fee, or rather, I want the owner to get what they expect and not what they expect minus the Stripe fee.  So I looked into providing a transfer data amount (for the connected account), but when I do, I get this error:

```
Only one of `application_fee` and `transfer_data[amount]` can be specified.
```

Which is fair enough, so I removed the `application_fee` and add the `transfer_data[amount]` when the service fee is waived but the renter only pay the price set in the line item, which actually makes sense.
So I'm wondering where the Stripe fee will be subtracted from?  From my Stripe account, or from what the owner will get.
I did some testing and it looks like the owner will get the right amount (120 in my test; which is what was shown on the Checkout page) but I'm not sure about the Stripe fee.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you described, you are using [Destination Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges). In that flow, the Checkout Session is created on your platform and will create the PaymentIntent and Charge right there. Then a portion of the funds will be transferred to the connected account via a Transfer and give them the resulting amount in their balance.

In that flow, the **platform** (your account/business) pays Stripe's fees. You charge the customer a certain amount ($120) and pay Stripe's fees based on that amount ($3.78). Separately, you configure the Session to also send a portion of those funds to the connected account ($120) so you end up with a net of -$3.78 since you transferred the full amount to the connected account and you paid Stripe's fees.

What this means is that you have to first calculate what Stripe's fees would amount to **before** the payment happens. For example if you charge $120 and know the fees will be $3.78 then you would set `transfer_data[amount]: 11622` so that the connected account gets the remainder and you net $0.

The "problem" here is that you can't reliably calculate Stripe's fees ahead of time as you don't know which *payment method type* will be used. Some have lower fees, others have a fee based on whether it's an international payment and such.

Unfortunately, this means that there isn't a reliable way for you to model the flow of funds you are looking for without some subtle code changes. Instead of using the [Destination Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges) flow, you would have to use the [Separate Charges and Transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers) flow.
The main difference is that you will separate the "collection of the payment" from the "transfer of funds to the connected account" in two steps. This will allow you to charge the customer $120, get the net amount in your platform account. And then transfer that net amount reliably to the connected account to ensure you don't pay extra fees. The objects will all still be linked together as expected but the flow happens in two steps.

Note that for refunds and disputes, you will still have to cover those extra fees from your platform so you have to account for this in your pricing.
If you have follow up questions, I think [Stripe's support team](https://support.stripe.com/contact) will be better equipped to help you than StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks a lot @koopajah for this very thorough answer.  Ok so the platform (us) will pay the Stripe fee, which makes sense.  Seems like we (our company) need to have available funds in our account to be able to cover that.  I'm guessing this is the way to do that: https://stripe.com/docs/add-funds ?  As long as we have enough money in our account these calls won't fail but will they fail if we don't or will we just get a notice to add funds if we don't have enough?

Comment: The calls wouldn't fail whether you have money or not as long as you use `source_transaction` to link the two together. But yes it's usually best to have funds in your own platform account to cover refunds for examples. Most platforms with a model like yours switch to manual Payouts for their own account to build up a balance over time.